# Copy to both X11 clipboards from vim

Tags: x11, vim

As far as I can see, with VIM I can choose between

- `set clipboard=unnamed` - yank to X11's primary selection buffer (middle-mouse button paste)
- and `set clipboard=unnamedplus` - yank to to X11's clipboard buffer (Ctrl-V paste in most GUI apps)

Is there a way to make it do *both* at the same time?

I usually use middle-mouse paste but that doesn't work everywhere so I'd like my selections to also be available in the clipboard buffer.

(I'm aware I could do `"+y` but I'd like to have that automatically)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For yanks, Vim supports setting *both* `unnamed` and `unnamedplus`:

```
:set clipboard=unnamed,unnamedplus
```

From `:help clipboard-unnamedplus`:

> ```
>       When "unnamed" is also included to the
>       option, yank operations (but not delete, change or
>       put) will additionally copy the text into register
>       '*'.
> ```